# Check for Time/Date Conflict php

Tags: php

I am currently developing a simple student scheduling application for a school enrollment. I have created two tables for subject schedule and reserve subject for the student. for schedule subject 1. subject code with Pk sched_id and for reserve subject code  FK subid, Day,labday, lecturetime, labtime. When a user select subject from schedule it will inserted to reservsub. I need the feature of checking for a day/labday time/labtime conflict for every subject that have been selected. For example:

User select subject with TTh  9:00am - to 11:00am day and lectime
And in reservetable it has  Thursday 10:30am - 12:30pm day and lectime

How do I build a script and/or function that would warn the user that it have a time conflict in php?

Thank you in advance.

here's the code for display the schedule and select

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubjecschedule  where Sem='".$_SESSION['sem']."' and Schoolyear='".$_SESSION['Sy']."' order by Subject")or die(mysql_error());

        $i=0;
        $b =1;  
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){ 
                        echo "<tr ><td align=' '><input id='send' name='reserv[$i]' type='image' src='images/Select.gif' onclick='addRow('myTable')' /> </td>
                        <td align=' '>".$row['Subject']."<input type='hidden' name='subj[$i]' value=".$row['Subject']."><input type='hidden' name='control[$i]' value=".$row['sched_id']."></td>
                          <td align=' '>".$row['section']."  </td>
                        <td align=' '>".$row['Lec']."-".$row['Lab']."  </td>

                        <td align=' '>".$row['Descriptive']." </td>
                        <td align=' '>".$row['Day']."<br/>".$row['Labday']." </td>

                        <td align=' '>".$row['LecTime']."<br/>".$row['LabTime']."  </td>

                        <td align=' '>".$row['Room']."<br/>".$row['Labroom']." </td>
                        <td align=' '>".$row['capacity']." </td>
                        <td >".$row['Slot']." </td>

                        </tr>";

        $i++;


                        }


    if (isset($_POST['reserv'])){
            if(!empty($_POST['reserv'])){
                $a = current(array_keys($_POST['reserv']));
                                $control=$_POST['control'][$a];



                                        }

                        }
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubjecschedule  where sched_id='".$control."' and Sem='".$_SESSION['sem']."' and Schoolyear='".$_SESSION['Sy']."'");
                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){
                                                    $cont=$row['sched_id'];
                                                    $sub=$row['Subject'];
                                                    $sec=$row['section'];
                                                    $lecture=$row['Lec'];
                                                    $laboratory=$row['Lab'];
                                                    $day=$row['Day'];
                                                    $daylab=$row['Labday'];
                                                    $lectime=$row['LecTime'];
                                                    $ltime=$row['LabTime'];
                                                    $room=$row['Room'];
                                                    $roomlab=$row['Labroom'];
                                                    $slot=$row['Slot'];
                                                    $caps=$row['capacity'];
                                            }
```

When subject is selected the tblreserv will verify if the data its already been save or it has a time conflict

```
    $verify2=mysql_query("Select * from tblsubjectreserv where stud_id='".$maxid."' and subject='".$sub."'")or die(mysql_error());                   
                        $ver=mysql_num_rows($verify2);
                            if($ver!=0){
                            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("This Subject already exists.");</script>';
                            }
                                else{ 


      $insert2=mysql_query("insert into tblsubjectreserv (sublink,stud_id,subject,section,Unitlec,Unitlab,timelec,timelab,daylec,Daylab,roomlec,roomlab,Sem,schoolyear)values('".$control."','".$maxid."','".$sub."','".$sec."','".$lecture."','".$laboratory."','".$lectime."','".$ltime."','".$day."','".$daylab."','".$room."','".$roomlab."','".$sem."','".$_SESSION['Sy']."')")or die(mysql_error());



}
```

but i dont know how to verify the day/time conflict.
im just a beginner please help me.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to this really depends on what type of database you are using and whether you want to do this validation in PHP or in the database. I would lean towards using triggers on the database to check for overlapping times on any insert, this way, if you end up having more than one interface to insert or update these record (e.g. front end app and a web service) then you don't need to re-write the logic, and you can let the database take care of maintaining the integrity. Your PHP could then catch the exception thrown on these particular inserts/updates (you are using PDO?) when the trigger throws an exception.

If you can add more information about what database you are using and also some more info about your table structures (all fields on both affected tables and their data types etc.) then you can get more specific answers on how the trigger needs to look.

I raised a similar question to this requirement a little while ago to which I received an excellent answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182800/1053722). This applies if you are using postgresql.

Comment: I think PDO would be an adventurous route and pioneering is always the best method to generate opportunities for strides in code efficiencies!

Comment: im using wamp5 mysql database and sorry for my lack of info. and yes i use database to check for time conflict when user select data from schedule table. 

thank you for replying

Comment: sorry sir i cant understand what PDO means since im beginner in php hope you can understand

Comment: Sorry sir i dont use postgresql and im not capable for that. hope you can understand

sorry for my lack knowledge of php

Comment: If you already have the db doing the checks for you, then I assume you have written some triggers to emulate complex check constraints? PDO can be found here <http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php>